# Vector's differences across data frames

Tags: r

I have 4 players, that are plying a game that have 6 "ideal" strategies. They can play variations of each strategy, so the plays does not match perfectly with how the strategy is, but i would like to add a column for the closest strategy that they are playing..

```
strategies<- data.frame(
name=c("strategy 1","strategy 2", "strategy 3","strategy 4","strategy 5","strategy 6"),
rebel=c(1,0,0,2,0,1),
cyber=c(0,1,3,0,0,2),
chrono=c(1,0,1,0,1,0),
void=c(0,0,0,1,0,0))

plays<- data.frame(
player=c("player 1","player 2","player 3","player 4"), rebel=c(1,0,3,NA),
cyber=c(1,NA,2,2),
chrono=c(1,1,0,3),
void=c(0,1,0,0))
```

What ineed to do is to grab player 1, compare him with each strategy and choose the strategy that is closer to the "ideal" one from "strategies" data frame. So i was thinking about

1. calculating the difference between "player 1" play against each strategy (i would have one vector for each posible strategy)
2. sum each number's absolute of that each vector
3. Choose the strategy that has the min value, that means that is closer than the others.

For "player 1", it would be "strategy 1, since

1. "player 1" -"strategy 1"= c(0,1,0,0).
2. 0+1+0+0=1
3. Strategy 1 has the min value, so its the closest strategy for "player 1"

There is any function that allows me to label every player's strategy with vectors?
I am not really good with vectors and I can not figure it out how to solve this without doing it manual.

Comment: You say *"closest strategy"*, so that implies a calculatable distance between a strategy and actual plays. If all you're looking for is a euclidean distance, then a euclidean distance can be used (square root of the sum of squared differences).

Answer (score 1):

Here's one method, though you need to define what `NA` means in terms of distance.

```r
strategies_list <- by(strategies[,-1], strategies[,1], unlist)
strategies_list[[1]]
#  rebel  cyber chrono   void 
#      1      0      1      0 
plays_list <- by(plays[,-1], plays[,1], unlist)
plays_list[[1]]
#  rebel  cyber chrono   void 
#      1      1      1      0 
dists <- outer(plays_list, strategies_list,
               Vectorize(function(a, b) sqrt(sum((a-b)^2)), vectorize.args=c('a','b')))
dists
#           strategies[, 1]
# plays[, 1] strategy 1 strategy 2 strategy 3 strategy 4 strategy 5 strategy 6
#   player 1          1   1.414214   2.236068    2.00000   1.414214   1.414214
#   player 2         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
#   player 3          3   3.162278   3.316625    2.44949   3.741657   2.000000
#   player 4         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
```

(If you don't know `Vectorize` ... the function given to `outer(..., FUN=)` is called once, with two lists/vectors. If the `FUN`ction only works on one pair at a time, then it will fail there. However, `Vectorize` takes a *function* and returns a *function* that calls the original for each argument. While it normally is used for just the first argument if the function, in this case we need it to vectorize/iterate-across two arguments, so we use `vectorize.args=` to indicate the args that need to be vectorized.)

That's the start. We can find which is the best strategy for each player with the following, though note that the all-`NA` rows lead to empty returns,

```r
min_dists <- apply(dists, 1, which.min)
min_dists
# $`player 1`
# strategy 1 
#          1 
# $`player 2`
# integer(0)
# $`player 3`
# strategy 6 
#          6 
# $`player 4`
# integer(0)
```

We can try to deal with it this way:

```r
unlist(replace(min_dists, !sapply(min_dists, length), NA))
# player 1.strategy 1            player 2 player 3.strategy 6            player 4 
#                   1                  NA                   6                  NA
```

where the integer value (1 and 6) are the indices on your `strategies` frame, and `NA` indicates nothing is close. (The names, e.g., `"player 1.strategy 1"` might be informative, but it's far better to not try to parse them for the actual strategy.)

Comment: Ivan Cereghetti, does this answer your question? If so, please accept it. Thank you!